# Products details with color and size magento 2 rest

Tags: rest, magento-2.0

how I can use Magento rest API for products and product details in Magento 2 rest.

I am using below filters for configurable products

```
example.net/index.php/rest/V1/products?searchCriteria[pageSize]=5
&searchCriteria[currentPage]=1
&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][field]=type_id
&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][value]=configurable
&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][conditionType]=eq
```

Now how i can load simple product details which are linked with above configurable products with color and size

Answer (score 1):

In order to get children details of the configurable product you can simply call

```
GET /V1/configurable-products/{sku}/children
```

using the sku of your configurable.

Have a look here [api call list](http://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/#!/configurableProductLinkManagementV1/configurableProductLinkManagementV1GetChildrenGet)